# How to jump to a folder in File Explorer's Quick Access using a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

How to jump to a folder in File Explorer's Quick Access using a keyboard shortcut? I forgot what it was and Google couldn't help.

Answer (score 6):

It’s <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> then the corresponding number.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same question. After digging a lot, I found [File Explorer keyboard shortcuts every Windows 10 user should know](https://winaero.com/blog/file-explorer-keyboard-shortcuts-every-windows-10-user-should-know/).

They point out that once File Explorer is open, <kbd>F6</kbd> will jump your focus from the menu bar to the navigation pane to the file pane. – I personally can't get to the menu bar with <kbd>F6</kbd>, but after repeated presses, the navigation pane is focused.

I figured out on my own that once in the navigation pane, the <kbd>Home</kbd> key will take you to the top. Ta-da! quick access. Then using your arrow keys will take you to the folder you want.

tldr; <kbd>F6</kbd> repeatedly until nav pane is focused,
+<kbd>Home</kbd> key = quick access.

Comment: This answer is gold. Not sure why it isn't upvoted more.

Answer (score 0):

For me, <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> works best from what I found.

Answer (score -2):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd>

This is a very straightforward question, but just providing the keystrokes makes the answer too short for SuperUser to accept.  So, I will add this additional text, to make the answer acceptable.  I may as well also provide this hyperlink: [TechNet: Navigate Windows Explorer More Quickly with These Keyboard Shortcuts](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee851673.aspx).

Comment: Question asks for focusing [quick access](http://img.wpxbox.com/Quick-Access-File-History-Windows-10-1024x576.png), but you provide a solution for address bar. Also question is about windows 10, and your proivided link is about windows 7, ...

Comment: @MátéJuhász I went into Windows 10, and looked in Explorer for something called "Quick Access", and found that was in the address bar.  So I was interpreting "Quick access" as a new (Windows 10) term for what Windows 7 called the address bar (which can be used as a drop-down box).

Comment: Quick access are the replacement of the favorites you see in Win7 Explorer